# Can I limit the size of files to be included in tar in a directory to include atomic files?

Tags: shell, tar

I have a directory having multiple files with different sizes

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

I want to limit create multiple tar files with some maximum fixed size(say 100 MB). Such that whole file is included in the tar or not included in the tar(If file size is greater than fixed size maybe throw an error)

I am aware of split function:

- Creating tar
- Splitting with desired chunk size

The problem with above method is that resulting tar files can't be extracted individually.

Could anyone help with the solution(or provide an alternative solution)

Answer (score 0):

The following script takes two or more arguments.  The first is the total size
of the set of files to use.  The remaining arguments are passed to find so you
can give a directory as an argument.  The script assumes that filenames
are "well behaved" and won't contain spaces, newlines, or anything
else that would confuse the shell.

The script prints out the largest files that will fit in the given size.  This
is not necessarily the most space consuming set of files, but finding that
efficiently in the general case is the Knapsack problem, which I am unlikely to
solve here.

You could change the `sort -rn` to `sort -n` to start with the smallest
files first.

```
#!/bin/sh

avail=$1
shift
used=0

find "$@" -type f -print | xargs wc -c | sort -rn | while read size fn; do
        if expr $used + $size '>' $avail >/dev/null; then
                continue;
        fi
        used=$(expr $used + $size)
        echo $fn
done
```

The output of the script can be passed to pax(1) to create the actual archive.
For example (assuming you have called the script `fitfiles`):

```
sh fitfiles 10000000 *.txt | pax -w -x ustar -v | xz > wdb.tar.xz
```